# What is the ADP option on a digital multimeter used for?

Tags: multimeter

What is the ADP option/range on a digital multimeter used for?
I've tried to find the answer by searching the net, but I couldn't find any explanation.

Comment: questions based on new terminology in electronics with new features ought "not" to be downgraded, particularily by those with no clue about the answer

Comment: @Nsiri Please be specific "I have a digital multimeter"which multimeter? Have you read your manual for the multimeter? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think this question could be on topic. Ok, it says that we shouldn't have questions about the "function of a specific device" in the forum rules, but this is actually a broader question about the terminology of multimeter instruments in general and I can't see why it should be off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. A [multimeter manual](http://www.sanwa-meter.co.jp/prg_data/goods/img/PH41338256467.pdf) with an ADP setting.*

It's to allow use of an ADaPtor. In the example it's a current probe adaptor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc6uXi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. A current probe connected to the ADP input. In this case there would be a shunt resistor to convert the current into a voltage to feed into the ADP input. The ADP input should probably scale the input voltage into "amps" or whatever the probe is measuring.*

Comment: voltage range for this Adapter current probe is often selectable in better meters between 600mV or 60mV

Comment: I believe "ADP" in this case stands for Adapter as shown in the paragraph heading. The multimeter merely converts the analog voltage out of the current probe into a current reading, hardly worthy of Automatic Data Processing.

Comment: Thanks @Transistor
Can you explain how to read voltage from this clamping prob?
As I know, This type of clamping prob works like a current trnsfomer. But,How it measures voltage?

Comment: You don't read voltage. That's a current clamp so it's for measuring current without contacting the wires or interrupting the circuit. For voltage you just touch the regular probes to the terminals.

Comment: Current probes are rated in Volts per Amp

Answer (score 1):

ADP or Automatic Data Processing is incorporated in some modern measuring equipment. Such equipment can process information comming from a dedicated sensor and present automatically a translated and direct usable format.
The Fluke 87V is such a multimeter. It can measure AC and DC current with the same probe.